# How to return non-const iterator from function taking a const reference to a container

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, iterator, constants

I am trying to write a template function to return the lexicographical last element in a container.

From my understanding of const correctness, since the function doesn't modify the template argument reference it should be const correct. How would I return a non-const iterator?

In other words, the function doesn't modify the containers elements because it is constant, but that guarantee shouldn't extend to the returned iterator should it?

I wish to express that the function does not modify anything but the returned iterator could allow the caller to do so.

```
#include<iterator>

template<typename T>
typename T::iterator lexicographical_last(const T& container)
{
  typename T::const_iterator b, last = container.begin();
  while (b != container.end())
    {
      if (b < last) last = b;
      ++b;
    }
  return last;
}
```

Comment: C++ doesn't support this subtlety, sorry. In the general case you'll just have to let the function take a reference to non-`const` argument. For some special cases such as `std::vector` it's possible to let the function just return an index, and for some other special cases the container type may offer some way to convert a returned const iterator to ordinary mutating iterator.

Comment: Note that the presented code (1) uses a possibly uninitialized variable `b`, and (2) compares the iterators instead of the items they refer to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you passed "container" by const reference, you are making a promise that this function won't modify it. That includes giving a non-const_iterator back.

If you need a non-const_iterator back, provide an overload that takes a mutable reference

```
template<typename T>
typename T::const_iterator lexicographical_last(const T& container);
template<typename T>
typename T::iterator lexicographical_last(T& container);
```

Comment: This is understandable. I just wanted to make sure something didn't exist for the case of the function not modifying the referenced "container" within the function body, but also returning a non-const iterator. Is there some reason that that would not be desirable or possible?

Comment: I think the reason is because there are no const methods on the standard containers that return mutable references. In general, circumventing const-correctness is generally bad. You need to make the case why the caller of this function needs a non-const iterator; In order to do what you want without an overload you will have to `const_cast` the container reference.