# Using reverse_iterator instead of const_reverse_iterator and getting nasty compiler warnings and errors

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, stdstring, reverse-iterator

I am currently in the process of learning C++ and encounter an issue while using

```
std::string::reverse_iterator
```

to reverse a string. I get nasty compiler errors when trying to run the function below. However, when I switch to using,

```
std::string::const_reverse_iterator
```

,the code compiles and runs successfully. Why is this the case, especially when the documentation for the language says that reverse iterators can be declared and used? What if I need to say, remove elements from a string while looping through it in reverse, and want to use a reverse iterator? A

```
const_reverse_iterator
```

surely would not suffice in this case. Any help would be much appreciated. :)

```
std::string reverse(const std::string &str)
{
    std::string::reverse_iterator r_iter;
    std::string result;

    for (r_iter = str.rbegin(); r_iter < str.rend(); r_iter++) {
            result += (*r_iter);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Some of these errors are:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_iterator.h: In instantiation of ‘std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>::reverse_iterator(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iter>&) [with _Iter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]’:
chap6.cpp:40:34:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_iterator.h:148:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::__normal_iterator(std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::iterator_type)’
  : current(__x.base()) { }
```

and

```
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_iterator.h:775:26: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_iterator.h:760:11: note: candidate: constexpr __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::__normal_iterator(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)
     class __normal_iterator
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_iterator.h:760:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::iterator_type {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >}’ to ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&’
```

Comment: Could you cite the compiler errors please, irrespective of how nasty they may appear to you?

Comment: please add the error in the question

Comment: not a dupe but same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48533336/how-to-return-non-const-iterator-from-function-taking-a-const-reference-to-a-con

Comment: Errors are included in the post.

Comment: From the looks of it, it seems to be an issue with reverse_iterator not being of class  normal_iterator, but const_reverse_iterator being one, which I do not really understand at all.

Comment: dont get confused by `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator` thats an implementation detail that you actually shouldnt worry about (unless you get a nasty error message ;). "officially" there is no class `normal_iterator`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `const std::string`, which means that you can only do `const` things to it. There are two overloads of [`std::string::rbegin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rbegin):

```
reverse_iterator rbegin();
const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const;
```

The first is unavailable to you, but the second is not.

```
std::string reverse(const std::string &str)
{
    std::string result;

    for (auto r_iter = str.rbegin(); r_iter != str.rend(); r_iter++) {
            result += *r_iter;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Note that you don't even need the loop, because you can construct a `std::string` from a pair of iterators, see [overload (6)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)

```
std::string reverse(const std::string &str)
{
    return /* std::string */ { str.rbegin(), str.rend() };
}
```

Comment: Overload (6) to the rescue. A recurring theme with the standard library.

Comment: @Caleth Wow, elegant solution with that last part! However, would you be able to elaborate on the syntax of '{str.rbegin(), str.rend()}', and why you didn't need to use an overloaded constructor for std::string (i.e. - return std::string(str.rbegin(), str.rend())?

Comment: @ＧＵＣＣＩＭＡＮＥ `{}` is one of the syntaxs of [initialising an object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization). The `std::string` is optional, the expression `{ str.rbegin(), str.rend() }` is in a context expecting a `std::string`, so it means "construct a `std::string`" with or without the explict mention of `std::string`

Comment: @Caleth Awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`str` is passed as `const&` so you cannot erase elements from it and you also cannot get a non-const iterator to it, if you want to modify it you need to remove the const:

```
std::string reverse(std::string &str)
                //  ^---------------------- no const if you want to modify it !!!
{
    std::string::reverse_iterator r_iter;
    std::string result;

    for (r_iter = str.rbegin(); r_iter < str.rend(); r_iter++) {
            result += (*r_iter);
    }

    return result;
}
```

It is a matter of const-correctness. You cannot get a non const iterator to a constant string, because that would allow you to modify elements of the string which is acutally const.

Also note that there is [`std::reverse` that you can use to reverse a string in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951796/how-to-reverse-an-stdstring). If you still want to keep the original your method could look like this:

```
std::string reverse(std::string str)
                //  ^ pass by value because we need a copy anyhow 
{
    std::reverse(str.begin(),str.end());    
    return str;
}
```

However, instead of first copying and then reversing, this can be done in one step, as shown in [Caleths answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52533418/4117728).

Comment: D'Oh! Thank you so much! My thinking was that I wasn't modifying the input at all, so I wanted to save the overhead of copying the argument into the parameter. But now I know that to get a non-const iterator to a parameter, the parameter has to not be constant! Thanks :D

Comment: @ＧＵＣＣＩＭＡＮＥ it doesnt matter if you **do** modify the string. You also cannot do `const int x; int& y = x;` even if you never use the reference `y` to modify `x`

Answer (score 3):

The whole const correctness issue [user463035818 pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52533242/817643) aside. You are exhibiting some unidiomatic (to C++) code writing habits.

For one, don't define `r_iter` before you need it, rather limit it to the scope of the loop. Beyond that, this is a case where you really don't care about the exact type of the iterator. You just want *the correct* iterator type from the member function.

So just use `auto` for the type of the iterator.

```
std::string reverse(const std::string &str)
{
    std::string result;

    for (auto r_iter = str.rbegin(); r_iter < str.rend(); r_iter++) {
            result += (*r_iter);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now your code is const correct by default. And if you *do* try to modify the input string by mistake, hopefully the error will be much clearer than when simply choosing the wrong iterator type inadvertently.

Comment: when pushing for idiomatic, imho you have to mention `std::reverse` which would be the idiomatic way to reverse a string...

Comment: @user463035818 `std::reverse` is in place. This is returning a new `std::string`

Comment: @user463035818 - There's two reason I don't. (1) You already did :) (2) Sometimes it's beneficial to re-invent part of the wheel to learn.

Comment: @Caleth hm yes and with your answer I think we have all possibilities covered ;)

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks! I will get familiar with 'auto' and start using it more. It seems to be very powerful, but I have just been taking baby steps and doing typing the long way to get my feet wet.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `str` of your function is a const-type argument. The rbegin() should return a const-type iterator. This is reasonable.

The declaration of rbegin() is as follows:

```
      reverse_iterator rbegin();
const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const;
```

So you can remove the `const` keyword from the function's parameter list to make it run or modify the `str` via reverse_iterator.